# Webhook/callback for S3 GET requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, get, amazon-ec2

At the moment we proxy GET (download) requests to S3, through an EC2 instance. The reason for doing this is because we want to know how much traffic a specific file has had.

Now we would like to be able to not use that proxy. But we would still need that information. Is there any way of doing this?

What I would like is a webhook/callback to a specific server. Or maybe read it in live/realtime from a log file.

Is there any way of achieving this? Been searching for the answer for quite some time now, but maybe we're not thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on [logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html) for the S3 bucket, then (optionally) send the client directly to the bucket.

The log format includes "Bytes Sent" as well as "Object Size" and a number of other goodies including the remote IP, referring page, and request URI with query string.

Logs are not real-time of course, but you'll find a new log dropped into your bucket every few minutes.  Retrieve it, parse it, store the interesting content if you want to, and then delete it if you don't want to pay monthly storage costs on the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the request URLs the same, pointing to your EC2 instance. But instead of proxying the content from S3 to the client through your EC2 instance, have your EC2 instance redirect the user to the S3 URL.

Use an expiring signed URL for the redirect. Your EC2 instance can create the appropriate URL on each request, expiring in a few minutes. That way there's time for the client to fetch the S3 resource but bookmarking it won't work because it will have expired when they try it later. So they always have to go to your EC2 instance to get the resource, allowing you to control and log access, but you don't have to proxy the content itself.

Comment: Thanks. I knew this already, though. My problem is that I want to know how much data was transferred. So if a file is 10MB then 10 request downloaded the file fully, but one only downloaded 1MB. In total this file have now used 101MB of bandwidth. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to keep track of how big partial downloads were, or just assume that all downloads complete? If the latter, your EC2 instance can use the S3 API (or even just a HEAD HTTP request) to see how big the S3 object is before redirecting the user, and log that size. But in the other case, once you've redirected the client to S3, you don't know what happens. You may be able to turn some S3 logging on. After all, AWS knows how much was downloaded because they charge for it.